# How to group_by() and subset within mutate?

Tags: r, tidyr, dplyr

I'm looking for a way to make a computation over two grouped_by variables:

```
 Age <- sample(c("4", "5", "6", "adult"), 20, replace = TRUE)
 letter <- sample(c("a", "c", "d"), 20, replace = TRUE)
 measurement <- sample(1.5:50.5, 20, replace = TRUE)

 df <- data_frame(Age, letter, measurement)
```

I want to group_by Age and letter

```
 df2 <- df %>%
     group_by(Age, letter)
```

but then I want to calculate the difference between the median measurement from one subset of Age and another:

```
 df2 <- df %>%
     group_by(Age, letter) %>%
     mutate(diff = median(measurement[Age=='adult']) - median(measurement[Age!='adult']))
```

I want the difference between 'measurement' (from adults) and 'measurement' (from each age group) for each age group and letter combination. I currently generate NAs; my approach is not correct. There must be a better way.

Comment: > I want the difference between 'measurement' (from adults) and 'measurement' (from each age group) for each age group and letter combination ==> 

When you groupby "Age" we are looking do some aggregations within that age group., such as differences between sub-categories within that age group. 

Once you group by age group, it doesn't make sense to run calculations outside that group.

May be you want to first groupby age group, calculate a summary statistic (such as median) for each age group, and then take the differences between age groups in a different operation ?

Comment: It might help to clarify what the output should look like for your example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to compute a difference between a fixed value (the median among adults) and a value that varies across groups.

Since the dataframe is grouped, you need to use the original dataframe in the calculus. Also, as you want only one value for each group, you don't want to `mutate` but to `summarise`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Age, letter) %>%
  summarise(diff = median(measurement) - median(df$measurement[df$Age=='adult'])
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick to the `dplyr` pipeline, you could first mutate a dummy variable which holds the median, and then use the first occurrence of this variable in the summarise call.

```
df %>%
  #group_by(letter) %>% #might also be interesting
  mutate(dummy=median(measurement[Age=='adult'])) %>% 
  group_by(Age, letter) %>%
  summarise(diff = median(measurement) - dummy[1]))
```

This might be less optimized, but it allows to group before calculating the fixed median, which might be interesting too.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the median for the adults first:

```
adultMedian <- df %>%
    filter(Age == "adult") %>%
    summarise(adultMedian = median(measurement)) %>%
    pull()

df %>%
    group_by(Age, letter) %>%
    mutate(diff = median(measurement) - adultMedian)
```

Which results in

```
   Age   letter measurement  diff
   <chr> <chr>        <dbl> <dbl>
 1 5     a              9.5 -15  
 2 adult c             24.5  -5  
 3 5     c             12.5 -12  
 4 6     d             18.5   6  
 5 adult a             27.5   3  
 6 adult d             37.5   3.5
 7 4     c             11.5   0.5
 8 6     d             31.5   6  
 9 5     c             32.5 -12  
10 6     c             18.5  -6  
11 5     d             49.5  25  
12 4     d             50.5  26  
13 4     c             38.5   0.5
14 6     d             30.5   6  
15 adult c              4.5  -5  
16 adult c             14.5  -5  
17 5     c              7.5 -12  
18 4     a             24.5   0  
19 adult c             49.5  -5  
20 adult d             18.5   3.5
```